How can I figure out macOS privacy settings when an app asks again for permissions it already has been granted?
I feel like this happens fairly regularly - I get a request from an app to grant permissions, I click to grant it, and they are already enabled.
In the screenshot below this is after a patch-level version update, so maybe they are registered to a different version of the app? After doing this I toggled Bartender off and got the alert with a 'quit and reopen' button that I would expect when toggling them on.
I’m looking for technical details how this mechanism actually works since it appears to me, MacOS or the app doesn’t know what permissions are set already.

Does it suggest something deeper is wrong?

Following the instructions at https://www.macbartender.com/Bartender5/PermissionIssues/ to "remove Bartenders permissions completely and re-add them" has fixed the issue for me.

See my answer below - remove and re-add bartender!

I think I found a partial answer in Bartender's own troubleshooting. I suppose this is the answer - MacOS has 'an issue.' That said removing and re-adding the permissions did fix it for me.

macOS has an issue that can cause Apps (including Bartender) to not be given Accessibilty and Screen Recording permissions correctly,
even though they have been granted by the user in System Settings, this results in Bartender showing its window requesting the permissions.
To fix this try removing Bartender from the permissions using the “-“ button, then re-adding it.

